# Kanji type and history behind kanji 蝶

Tags: kanji

I'm wondering what type of kanji 蝶 is (like if it's a pictogram, ideogram, etc) and if anyone knows the history behind the kanji itself. I really like this kanji, but there's not much about it from where I've been looking.

Comment: Where did you look?

Answer (score 5):

[「[蝶]{チョウ}」](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%9D%B6#Readings) (*butterfly*) is a [phono-semantic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Phono-semantic_compound_characters) compound, comprised of semantic [「[虫]{まむし}」](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%99%BA#Alternative_forms) (*poisonous snake* > *worm, insect*) and phonetic [「[枼]{ヨウ}」](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9E%BC#Readings):

- 「虫」 appears here as a semantic classification component for snakes, worms, insects, and other non-fish slimy or wet animals (e.g. 「蛙」 *frog* and 「蟹」 *crab*);
- 「枼」 is the original form of [「[葉]{ヨウ}」](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%91%89#Readings), and appears as a phonetic hint in 「蝶」, 「葉」, and [some other characters](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9E%BC#Derived_characters) (most of which aren't used in modern Japanese).

Comment: It seems reasonable to assume 枼 also acted as a semantic component. Butterflies do look like leaves in comparison to other bugs. So do flatfish.

Comment: @aguijonazo There's a subtle difference for describing characters here. 枼's original meaning is *tree leaves*. The morpheme which 枼 represents (Baxter-Sagart OC: **/\*lap/**, *flat object*) is the one that connects the meanings (*flatfish* in 鰈, etc.), not 枼 itself, so 枼 is not a semantic component. In other words, 枼's *sound* provides the semantic connection & etymology, not its meaning (tree leaves) or shape (picture of a tree with emphasised leaves).